# jquery mobile popup close button - how to close without going back?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, youtube, popup

I'm using the new popup dialog in jquery mobile 1.2.0 to display a bunch of youtube videos. Here are the popup examples I'm using:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/popup/popup-iframes.html

Notice the maps example... it's a fancybox style with a close button. I've made my video popup do the same thing. The difference is the additional close link, added to the popup like so:

```
<a href="##" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
```

Here's the problem: After opening one video and then closing it, then opening the next video and closing it, the first video shows up again. I think it's because the previous video is where "back" is in the history, and the close box is implemented as "back".

Is there a built in way to implement the close box as a true "close", or would I need to do it via javascript?

Comment: Seems like closing a popup (even when not using the close button - ie, tapping outside the popup) is done by going back. I'm not entirely sure about this... all I know is how it behaves at this point. When my last page view had a previously opened popup, that popup gets opened again. My implementation might be slightly different than normal - I'm using the same popup to display all vidoes... I simply change the src attribute for the iframe before opening the popup using: ('#popupid').popup('open');

Comment: Here's essentially what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/zFete/2/ I am using the same popup to display multiple videos. I tried to post a jsfiddle yesterday, but there's issues with this running this on FF and Chrome having to do with Flash. As you'll see in my mods to your jsfiddle, you have to click the button 2x for the popup to show, and then there's some other issues as well, which are shown in the console. The dev site that's actually using this is at: http://ehealthmobile.redtopia.com under the "team" icon from the home page.

Comment: @Phil... just wondering if you had any ideas? I think it might have something to do with the hash, which is added to the URL when opening the popup. I wonder if there's a way to open the dialog without adding the hash... and then closing it. I would hate to have to create separate popups for each video because the list of videos can vary. I suppose I could dynamically create a different popup for each video.

Comment: I think the issue is you're using the same popup but changing the url to point to another video. Great Idea but I'm not sure that's how jQM team thought about doing. I would make an issue to see if you could get anywhere with jQM but also maybe create two separate popups just to test out my theory

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue as I'm using a popup to display an error message, which then closes after 3 seconds. Sometimes the close causes the main page to go back to the previous one. The popup functionality here seem badly implemented to me as this behaviour simply shouldn't happen.

Comment: @Ian, I'm with you... I'll get back on this issue hopefully this week and keep this question up to date. I think it has something to do with the hash and history... if you look at the URL after you open the dialog, does it have a hash? And then looking at the close button, you'll see it's actually a go back (at least in my example).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

@Redtopia, thanks for the response. I fixed my issue by setting the `myPopup.popup({ history: false });` option on the popup. Then everything works fine.

Comment: I'm unable to try this at the moment... I'll get back to this thread when I figure things out. My problem is that I have a single popup that I want to use for multiple pages, and sometimes, depending on the URL, the same page loads twice, giving me two (or more) of the same dialog. I need to figure out a way to deal with this before I can try your solution.

Comment: Before opening the dialog, couldn't you check first to see if it's already visible, and if so, don't bother opening it?

Comment: That's not the issue... In the template for my CMS, I'm inserting the popup into the page. But because jquery mobile will sometimes cache pages in the DOM, there are times when my popup (with the same ID) exists multiple times in the DOM. I need to figure out a way to include a popup into each page with a unique id, and then the javascript will know which ID to use.

Comment: I finally got it all working. I had to inject a popup into every page that uses one... a little complicated, but it works nicely. I think I'm finally getting the hang of how jquery mobile works. For my template-driven site, I now avoid using DOM IDs because you end up with duplicates when they're part of your template. This messed me up quite a bit!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. That's my main issue with jQuery Mobile, me not understanding how everything works nor the best practices as in what type of stuff should I do in pagecreate, and what about pagebeforeshow and pageshow? Some guidelines would help!

Comment: It is correct answer but i would like to add some more info. this solution worked for me. In my case i am creating dynamic pop up so this solution worked for me when i used myPopup.popup({ history: false }); after creating pop up and before opening it.

Comment: Works for me! Actually I added `data-history="false"` in the HTML  -->

`<div data-role="popup" data-history="false" id="myPopup"></div>`